# Let $B={\{x^2, x, 1}\}$ and $S= {\{x^2+x, 2x-1, x+1}\}$ be two basis of $P_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, invariant-subspace

Let $B={\{x^2, x, 1}\}$ and $S= {\{x^2+x, 2x-1, x+1}\}$ be two basis of $P_2$. Let $i_b$ and $i_s$ be the coordinates maps induced on $P_2$ by these two basis. Let$T: P_2\to P_2$ be a liner transformation such that

$[T]_{B,S}$=$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 &0 \\-1&3&5\\2 & 2&-2 \end{bmatrix}$

a) Prove that $ker(T)$=$i_b^{-1}(Null([T]_{B,S}))$ and $i_s(Im(T))=Col([T])_{B,S})$.

I know that $[T(x)]_B=[T]_{B,S}[x]_B$

but what is $i_B$ and what is its $Im$??

I am stuck with finding the $ker(T)$, I would be appreciate if someone can walk me through this problem.

Comment: Im(T) is the image or Range of the transformation.And i think for Ker(T) you just need to solve $[T]_{B,S}.\bar x=\bar 0$.

Comment: @emonhossain is it the same as $Null([T]_{B,S})$ ?